# AXIS2C: Invalid Transport Protocol, HTTPS transport not enabled

Tags: c, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, axis2c

I'm trying to use AXIS2/C and a .wsdl file to talk to a server and request some functions. But I do get the following error message. I can't seem to find any relevant information about whats going wrong.

It seem to me that AXIS2 needs some more information, because apparently it's still trying to talk HTTP and not HTTPS as desired:

```
[info]  Starting addressing out handler
[debug] ..\..\src\modules\mod_addr\addr_out_handler.c(133) No action present. Stop processing addressing
[debug] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_transport_sender.c(250) ctx_epr:https:<URL_TO_SERVICE_HERE>
[debug] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_transport_sender.c(893) using axis2 native http sender.
[debug] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_sender.c(437) msg_ctx_id:urn:uuid:<UUID_HERE>
[error] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_client.c(282) Transport protocol is unsupported by axis2
[error] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_client.c(283) Invalid Transport Protocol, HTTPS transport not enabled.
[error] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_client.c(555) client data stream  null or socket error for host <URL> and 443 port
[error] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_client.c(559) A read attempt(HTTP) for the reply without sending the request
[error] ..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\http_sender.c(1402) status_code < 0
[error] ..\..\src\core\engine\engine.c(179) Transport sender invoke failed
```

The first AXIS2C function that fails is the auto genereated function:

```
axis2_stub_op_<service>_<function>
```

i.e., the function that actually sends the data. All other AXIS2C functions up to that point work fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ./configure the build with the `--enable-ssl` option? Are you aware that Axis2/C is unmaintained and buggy?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I build with `--enable-ssl`. I'm gonna double check though. I do know that it is unmaintained but I use it in another project and it works fine. Do you know of any alternatives? I do need SOAP/WSDL/HTTPS